# datatable.Rows.Find doesn't work

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

```
        Dim datatable_default_view As DataTable = _datatable.DefaultView.ToTable
        Dim servicenumber As String = datatable_default_view.Rows.Item(e.RowIndex)("Service Number").ToString
'gets the service number of the selected row

        If _datatable.PrimaryKey.Length = 0 Then
            Dim keys(0) As DataColumn
            keys(0) = _datatable.Columns("Service Number")
            _datatable.PrimaryKey = keys
        End If

        Dim datarow_edited As DataRow = _datatable.Rows.Find(servicenumber)

        Try
            MsgBox("Record" + datarow_edited("service number") + " was edited")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        End Try
```

I've put this code under the DatagridView_CellEndEdit event

The Problem:
The 'data_row edited' variable doesn't get initialized when exiting the cell in edit mode using the **keyboard** (ie: pressing the down/up arrow).
If I use the mouse it works as expected. Why is this ? Is it a known bug I'm using VB.net 2008. Please Help

I've uploaded a sample project, with sample data [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=923085ae74a2e362&resid=923085AE74A2E362!300&parid=923085AE74A2E362!107&authkey=!AKxMg3O5XCi17ik). Check it out if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried you example solution with VS 2010 and it's working as intended. DataRow gets initialized correctly, also when switching rows with arrow keys.

Edit:

Got you now, sorry.

Looks like some async issue behind the scenes.

Maybe handling RowChanged event of the datatable itself could be a workaround for you

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Private _datatable As DataTable
    Dim conn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Members Database.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(conn)
        Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter


        Dim _branchname As String = "A BAUR"
        Dim cmd As String = "Select [Service Number] ,[Name], [Gender], [Subscription]  from " + _branchname.Insert(0, "[") + "]"
        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, conn)
        _datatable = New DataTable
        adapter.Fill(_datatable)


        If _datatable.PrimaryKey.Length = 0 Then

            Dim keys(0) As DataColumn
            keys(0) = _datatable.Columns("Service Number")
            _datatable.PrimaryKey = keys
        End If


        AddHandler _datatable.RowChanged, AddressOf _datatable_RowChanged

        DataGridView1.DataSource = _datatable

    End Sub


    Private Sub _datatable_RowChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Data.DataRowChangeEventArgs)

        Dim servicenumber = e.Row("Service Number")

        Dim datarow_edited As DataRow = _datatable.Rows.Find(servicenumber)

        Try 
            MsgBox("Record" + datarow_edited("service number") + " was edited")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I'm using VS 2008 on XP (tried it on 7 as well) .I made this [**clip**](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=923085ae74a2e362&resid=923085AE74A2E362!302&parid=923085AE74A2E362!300&authkey=!AHGVjqhn6ODlJRo) to give you an idea of what's happening . Notice when I exit using the keyboard (2nd attempt) it gives an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim servicenumber As String =  _datatable.Rows(e.RowIndex)("Service Number").ToString()
```

Comment: I'm using DefaultView because I'm letting the user filter the data using a bindingSource .Just using _datatable.Rows(e.RowIndex) gives the RowIndex of the filtered table not the actual table :)